# SDL_BlitSurface always blurry. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, sdl

With my code, I simply want to display a png-image on the screen using SDL 1.2.15, no scaling involved. However, the image shown on the screen with the code below always comes out blurry and the colors are off (see attached image). What am I doing wrong?

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(400, 240, 24, SDL_HWSURFACE);
SDL_Surface *image = IMG_Load ( "/image.png" );
SDL_BlitSurface ( image, NULL, screen, NULL );
SDL_Flip(screen);
```

The image below shows the original image within the grey box (enlarged - each black stripe is one pixel wide, original dimensions are 11x11px) on the left and what the screen shows after executing the code above on the right.

[image]

Comment: Is there some specific reason you're using SDL1 instead of SDL2 ?

Comment: Yes - SDL2 has not been ported to the platform I'm coding for

Comment: Which platform is that?

Comment: Platform is Nintendo 3DS

Comment: You're not checking the return values of `BlitSurface` or `Flip` for errors, so that's the first thing to do. Also make sure your version of SDL_Image is correct.

Comment: Both functions `BlitSurface` and `Flip` are returning 0. SDL_image version is 1.2.12, SDL version is 1.2.15

Comment: Well, I can't actually run the code, since I don't have an older version of SDL and I don't have a Nintendo dev platform, but it looks like a pixel format problem. You're sure your PNG image is 24-bit color format? 32-bit is more common.

Comment: Can you repro on the bottom screen?

Comment: The PNG is 24 bit color and I can reproduce on the bottom screen. I did some more research and turns out that the image pixels look correct - also the screen pixels after the blit. Seems that rendering of the screen surface to the physical screen is where the issue can be found. AFAIK, this part of the SDL-code is platform specific. Will get in touch with the port author to get this checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was SDL implementation platform specific and thus not valid for SDL in general